# Sharepoint list formating isssue

Tags: sharepoint

I have the problem that no matter what i do my formatting doesnt work.
my goal is that if ganztägig is true, only the date and the word ganztägig is thair and if ganztägig is false , only the date and the time is thair. I tried everything but its not working.

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Ganztägig.displayValue]==TRUE,
    (toLocaleDateString(@currentField)),
  (toLocaleString(@currentField)))
"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFQ56.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swOPU.png)

Comment: Suggestion: Do not use non-ASCII characters for SharePoint fields. SharePoint has _two_ “names” per each field, InternalName and DisplayName. When you create the field, set it to e.g. "AllDay", which sets both. Then rename to "Ganztägig", which sets the DisplayName _only_. Then you can use "AllDay" in the code.

Comment: Providing "Ganztägig" is a boolean field, I'd try `=if([$Ganztägig], …)` only.

Comment: Thank You @OndrejTucny. but the if statment is still not working.`{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=if([$Ganztaegig]==TRUE,(toDateString(@currentField))+' Ganztägig',(toDateString(@currentField))+' '+(toLocaleTimeString(@currentField)))"
}` Do you know how to not show the seconds only mm and hh?

Comment: Remove the "==TRUE" part. Providing it is a Yes / No field, **you don't need to compare the value, just use it as you would use any kind of boolean**.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, if your Ganztägig column is yes/no column type, you could just replace [$Ganztägig.displayValue] with [$Ganztägig], then you will achieve your goal:

[image]

Comment: The if statment is still not working. `{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=if([$Ganztaegig]==TRUE,toDateString(@currentField),toLocaleString(@currentField)"
}`´and now it says erro when i want to safe it.

Comment: I tried it but its not working.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K0QK.png

Comment: Hi ZBHorizon, according to the screenshot you provided, you lack " ) " before " } ". The whole code should be    {    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",    "elmType": "div",    "txtContent": "=if([$Ganztaegig]==TRUE,toDateString(@currentField),toLocaleString(@currentField))" }

Answer (score 0):

If your `Ganztägig` column is of type "Yes/No" (Boolean), try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if([$Ganztägig],toLocaleDateString(@currentField),toLocaleString(@currentField))"
}
```

**Note**: Make sure you are using correct [internal name](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) of `Ganztägig` column in JSON.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)